# Make the mod message excerpt in the top bar more useful

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, top-bar

> moderator message 4 hours ago
>   *Evil Moderator* added a new message
>   Hello, I'm writing in reference to your Meta Stack Overflow account:   http://meta.stackoverflow....

Yeah.. that excerpt is not very helpful for mod messages (replies are a different thing).
What about removing the introduction part from the excerpt that's shown in the top bar? Since it's almost always the same it's easy to detect and to remove.

Actually I'd even go one step further and detect message templates that have not been modified and in that case only show the name of the template.

Comment: I think just showing the name of the template (instead of trying to intelligently analyze the message body) is the best way to go for initial messages.

Comment: I'm also okay with implementing the "Evil Moderator" part.

Comment: I'd suggest that seeing the recipient's username somewhere in the excerpt would be helpful.  Maybe at the end of the summary line? e.g., *Evil Moderator added a new message to abusive-user*

Comment: I'd also say include the user that was messaged. So something like "abusive to others sent to user123" would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going forward, for the very first moderator message (in a thread) that a moderator initiates, the moderator inbox message will have the following form:

```
<mod name> sent <template name> [with edits] to <recipient name>
```

No excerpt will show up, and the "with edits" text will only show up if the template has been edited.

Moderator evilness ranking in the message will be determined by number of flags handled compared to fellow moderators on the site.

Comment: Very clean, I like it. Will make it much easier to read on SO, at least.

Comment: This is an awesome answer but can I request clarification on the last point? Is more flags handled higher or lower on the evil score? And is this a high score wins or a low score wins scale?

Comment: @Caleb - the exact scoring is kept secret, 'cuase, y'know, we're evil.

Comment: This only applies to new messages, right?  I've looked at an older message, and it's still the same.

Comment: @Jamal - yes, hence "going forward" ;)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I thought it applied to both anyway. *refrains from sending mod message to self*